# Converting int to string and adding to an existin string in c++

Tags: c++, string

I was wondering how I could convert an int to a string and then add it to an existin string. i.e.

```
std::string s = "Hello";
//convert 1 to string here
//add the string 1 to s
```

I hope I'm making sense. Thank you very much in advance for any answer.

Comment: Does ‘*add*’ mean *append*?

Comment: @Biffen Yes, english is not my mother tongue so, sorry. I want the new string to be "Hello1".

Comment: `int i = 1; s.append(std::to_string(i));`

Comment: @Biffen: Nothing wrong with using "add" (talk to a Java guy). Although *concatenation* is a better word.

Comment: @Bathsheba No, nothing *wrong*, just wanted a clarification. Since numbers are involved, *add* could have a different meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "modern" way is to use `std::to_string(1)`. In fact, various overloads of `std::to_string` exist for different number types.

Putting this together you can write `std::string s = "Hello" + std::to_string(1);`

Alternatively you can use `std::stringstream` which *can* be faster due to fewer string concatenation operations which can be expensive:

```
std::stringstream s;
s << "Hello" << 1;
// s.str() extracts the string
```

Comment: Ok the std::to_string(1) did it. I also tried the stringstream one which seems better but I would have to make too many changes to my code just for one simple detail. At any rate, thank you very much. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3):

If the number you want to *append* is an integer or floating point variable, then use [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) and simply "add" it:

```
int some_number = 123;
std::string some_string = "foo";

some_string += std::to_string(some_number);

std::cout << some_string << '\n';
```

Should output

```
foo123
```

Comment: I did that but I only get some random characters in the output. (% . , etc).
(Along with the initial string of course)

Comment: @KostasKol Then you're doing something else wrong. The code in my answer [works fine](http://ideone.com/yEx7NE). If you don't get it to work, then create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show it in a new question, together with possible input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: could you believe I actually didn't see the <std::to_string(some_number)> part? I though I would just do <some_string += some_number>. It works! Thank you very much for the help.